# How to copy only part of the array to output in a mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have the following example of the mex file:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <random>

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
 int nIterations = 10;
 double *Out,K[nIterations];
 mxArray *mxOut;

 std::random_device rnd_device;
 std::mt19937_64 rg(rnd_device());
 std::normal_distribution<double> Xi(0,1);

 int nStep = 0;

 for (int i=0; i<nIterations;i++){
    K[i] = Xi(rg);
    nStep++;
    if (K[i]>0.2){break;}
 }
 plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(nStep,1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
 Out  = (double*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);

 // I want to avoid this cycle
 for (int i=0; i<nStep;i++){
    Out[i] = K[i];

 }
}
```

The main idea is that I know the maximal size of output (10 in this case), but from run to run the size of `K` may be different (from 1 to 10). Thus, I perform a copying loop at the end of the snippet.
**Is it possible to avoid the last loop in my example?**

Comment: Not 100% clear. You are not using `Out` after that assignment, do you? I have the feeling that you could simply remove most of the code without changing its outcome.

Comment: Out it is output of function - it sends it in a matlab

Comment: `Out` is local to the function. Do you mean you are writing to `plhs` via `Out`?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you my C++ is terrible...

Comment: Do you want to generate random numbers or it is an example?

Comment: It is an example, but in my real code, I also generate random numbers in this way. If You find something wrong, I would be happy to be informed.

Comment: You could save only the state of the random number generator + `nsteps` so you didn't need to allocate memory for `k`  and `Out`. However you will need again to generate random numbers based on the saved state and the nStep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can `#include <string.h>` and replace the loop with plain and basic memory copy:
`memcpy(Out,K,nStep * sizeof(*K));`

---

Another perhaps uglier solution is to allocate enough memory to store all iterations into `Out`, then reallocate memory with `mxRealloc` so that Matlab can properly track the memory allocation.

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(nIterations,1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
Out  = (double*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);

// draw up to nIterations numbers 
for (int i=0; i<nIterations;i++){
   Out[i] = Xi(rg);
   nStep++;
   if (Out[i]>0.2){break;}
}

// reallocate memory and set nb of rows
mxSetData(plhs[0],mxRealloc(Out,nStep * sizeof(*Out)));
mxSetM(plhs[0],nStep);
```

Comment: The [documentation to `mxSetM`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetm.html) says it is not necessary to reallocate the data. If the max size is 10, reallocating has no real advantage. If the max size is very large, it might. In any case, this is the right method, the `memcpy` method doesn’t avoid the data copy, and is likely not a whole lot faster than the loop, since it’s already copying doubles.

Comment: max size is from 1e3 to 1e6.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way in c.

Another workaround is to send your array and your nStep variable to matlab and handle the array slicing there.